# Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?

Tags: c

Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?

```
arr[2][5] = {"hello","hai"};
**ptr = arr;
```

Here why doesn't the double pointer (**ptr) work in this example?

Comment: What code have you compiled that's similar to the code in your question?

Comment: Run away from multidimensional arrays (except perhaps small ones).

Comment: @Alexandre C. Multidimensional arrays are simple, useful and efficient. Why would you want to run away from them?

Comment: @Shahbaz: they are not simple, and if you don't have C99 they are not useful either since they can't have variable length.

Comment: I inverted the question, so that it won't mislead future readers.

Answer (score 78):

I'm going to try to draw how

```
int array[10][6];
```

and

```
int **array2 = malloc(10 * sizeof *array2);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    array2[i] = malloc(6 * sizeof **array2);
```

look like in the memory and how they are different (And that they can't be cast to each other)

`array` looks like:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
| | | | | | | | | | | | | ..............| | | (10*6 elements of type int)
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
< first row >< second row> ...
```

`array2` looks like:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
| | | | | | | | | | | (10 elements of type int *)
 - - - - - - - - - - 
 | |     ....      |     _ _ _ _ _ _
 | |                \-->| | | | | | | (6 elements of type int)
 | |                     - - - - - -
 | |
 | |      _ _ _ _ _ _
 |  \ -->| | | | | | | (6 elements of type int)
 |        - - - - - -
 |
 |
 |      _ _ _ _ _ _
  \ -->| | | | | | | (6 elements of type int)
        - - - - - -
```

When you say `array[x][y]`, it translates into `*((int *)array+x*6+y)`

While, when you say `array2[x][y]`, it translates into `*(*(array2+x)+y)` (Note that for `array`, this formula also works (read to the end of the post, and then the comments)).

That is, a static 2d array is in fact a 1d array with rows put in one line. The index is calculated by the formula `row * number_of_columns_in_one_row + column`.

A dynamic 2d array, however is just a 1d array of pointers. Each pointer then is dynamically allocated to point to another 1d array. In truth, that pointer could be anything. Could be `NULL`, or pointing to a single variable, or pointing to another array. And each of those pointers are set individually, so they can have different natures.

If you need to pass the pointer of `array` somewhere, you can't cast it to `int **` (imagine what would happen. The `int` values of the cells of `array` are interpreted as pointers and dereferenced -> Bam! Segmentation fault!). You can however think of `array` as a 1d array of `int [6]`s; that is a 1d array of elements, with type `int [6]`. To write that down, you say

```
int (*p)[6] = array;
```

Comment: If `array` is allocated in memory as such as you've described how does [something like this](https://ideone.com/e7v8x8) still work? I can understand that `array[x][y]` translates to `*(((int *)array)+x*6+y)`, but why does `*(*(array + i) + j)` still work?

Comment: @KohányiRóbert, That's an excellent point. And in fact for a (not-dynamic) multidimensional array (`array` in this case), the two are equivalent. You need to pay attention to the type of `array` in the expression to understand it. First, notice that in `*(((int *)array)+x*6+y)`, I first cast `array` to `int *`. This essentially means `x*6+y` is an index to array of `int`s.

Comment: Now when you do `*(*(array + i) + j))`, you don't change the type of `array`. What's the type of `array`? It's `int (*)[6]`. What's the `sizeof` of that? It's `sizeof(int) * 6`. Now `*(array + i)` then becomes the same as `(int[6])((int *)array + i*6)` (makes sense?). Indexing that with j becomes `*((int *)array + i*6 + j)`.

Comment: Is `int *p[6] = array;` also valid? Do the parenthesis matter to the compiler?

Comment: @Rohan, the parentheses matter. `int *p[6]` is an array of 6 pointers. `int (*p)[6]` is a pointer to an array of 6 integers. This is quite similar to function pointers. `int *f()` and `int (*f)()` are different things.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer: still very useful 13 years later!

Answer (score 12):

In C, a two-dimensional array is an *array of arrays*.

You need a pointer-to-array to refer to it, not a double-pointer:

```
char array[2][6] = {"hello", "hai"};
char (*p)[6] = array;
//char **x = array;  // doesn't compile.
```

For a double pointer to refer to "2-dimensional data", it must refer to the first element of an *array of pointers*. But a 2-dimensional array in C (array of arrays) is not the same thing as an array of pointers, and if you just define a 2-D array, then no corresponding array of pointers exists.

The only similarity between the two is the `[][]` syntax used to access the data: the data itself is structured quite differently.

Answer (score 9):

Having pointer-to-pointer means that each row (or column, if you prefer to think of it that way) can have a different length from the other rows/columns.

You can also represent a 2D array by just a pointer to the start element, and an integer that specifies the number of elements per row/column:

```
void matrix_set(double *first, size_t row_size, size_t x, size_t y, double value)
{
  first[y * row_size + x] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Making an array of pointers to each row in order to obtain an object that "looks like" a multidimensional array of variable size is *an expensive design choice for the sake of syntactic sugar*. Don't do it.

The correct way to do a variable-sized multidimensional array is something like:

```
if (w > SIZE_MAX/sizeof *m/h) goto error;
m = malloc(w * h * sizeof *m);
if (!m) goto error;
...
m[y*w+x] = foo;
```

If you want it to "look pretty" so you can write `m[y][x]`, you should be using a different language, perhaps C++.

Comment: you can use variable-length arrays to let the compiler do the offset computation for you: `int (*foo)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *foo * rows)` makes it possible to use the familiar `foo[i][j]` syntax;

Comment: @Christoph: Indeed, if you have a C99 compiler, this works. You need to arrange to pass the dimensions properly to any function calls you pass the array to, though.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by talking about legal code.  What you've written (assuming a char in front of each declaration) won't compile, for several reasons: you have too many initializers (six char's for arr[0], and its size is 5), and of course, char** p doesn't have a type compatible with char arr[2][5].  Correcting for those problems, we get:

```
char arr[2][6] = { "hello", "hai" };
char (*p)[6] = arr;
```

Without any double pointer.  If you want to access single characters in the above, you need to specify the element from which they come:

```
char* pc = *arr;
```

would work, if you wanted to access characters from the first element in arr.

C++ doesn't have two dimensional arrays.  The first definition above defines an array[2] or array[6] of char.  The implicite array to pointer conversion results in pointer to array[6] of char.  After that, of course, there is no array to pointer conversion, because you no longer have an array.

Answer (score 0):

There is forever a decouple from language to representation.

To some extent, C is nearly *Dissendium*.

Take the above example, we are trying to assign or transform 2D array into another form,

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
int main() 
{ 
        char array[2][6] = {"hello", "hai"};
        int h, i;
        for (h = 0; h < 2; h++) 
                for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
                        printf("%c\n", *(*(array+h) + i));
        char (*p)[6] = array;
        for (h = 0; h < 2; h++) 
                for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
                        printf("%c\n", *(*(p+h) + i));
        char **x = array;
        for (h = 0; h < 2; h++) 
                        printf("%c\n", *(x+h));
}
```

And the output,

```
h
e
l
l
o

h
a
i



h
e
l
l
o

h
a
i



h
i
```

Nowadays compilers are so smart they probably will just warn instead of fail, i.e.

```
main.c:14:13: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  char **x = array;
```

At this point, we should be able to understand double pointer **is not** double array.

The first `h` is from `hello`, the second `i` is from `hai`. Notice the distance is 8 bytes, equal to **size of a pointer**.

Besides, we can also do,

```
char *y[2];
for (h = 0; h < 2; h++) 
        y[h] = array[h];
for (h = 0; h < 2; h++)
        printf("%s\n", y[h]);
for (h = 0; h < 2; h++)
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                printf("%c\n", *(*(p+h) + i));
```

But this assignment **is not** a one-line statement.

And the output,

```
hello
hai
h
e
l
l
o

h
a
i
```