# How to create this formula?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, memory-address

I've training / homework to create the following formula applied to C:

> How to calculate the address to an element in a matrix of integers, if
>   the starting address of the matrix is known, the size is known and the
>   row and the columns of the element is known.

Say the matrix is a[b][c].
The starting address is then `a` or equivalently `&a[0][0]`

Numbers of rows is b.

Number of columns is c.

Every element should have size `sizeof(int)` so then the address would be `a + b*sizeof(int) + a*sizeof(int)`

Is this formula correct?

Comment: All you need to verify is how a matrix is stored in C. Your reasoning is perfect.

Comment: @Keyser Fact seems to be that matrices are stored by rows, first the entire first row and so on. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `int array[b][c]` and you need to find the address of element `array[i][j]`.

```
a + i * c * sizeof(int) + j * sizeof(int)
```

where, `c * sizeof(int)` appears to be a row size, so a general formula for this is

```
array_start + i * row_size + j * item_size
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming arrays are stored row-major, that means if you have:

```
int array[N][M];
```

Then, first you have `M` `int`s corresponding to `array[0]`, then you have `M` `int`s corresponding to `array[1]` and so on.

Therefore:

- address of `array[0][c]` is given by: `(char *)array + c * sizeof(int)`
- address of `array[1][0]` is given by: `(char *)array + 1 * M * sizeof(int)`
  because there are `M` int for `array[0]`.
- address of `array[1][c]` is given by: `(char *)array + 1 * M * sizeof(int) + c * sizeof(int)`
- address of `array[2][0]` is given by: `(char *)array + 2 * M * sizeof(int)`
- You can hopefully see the pattern now. Address of `array[r][c]` is given by `(char *)array + r * M * sizeof(int) + c * sizeof(int)`
  that is, `r * M` to skipt the first `r` rows, and then `c` columns.

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7307699/912144) for more explanation on 2D memory layout. The same answer also contains memory layout of dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to think about it:

First calculate the index of that element, using this equation

```
i = c + r * w
```

where c is the column, r is the row and w is the width of the matrix/2D array (the number of columns)

Then multiply that by the size of an integer, that gives you the memory offset of the element from the base address

```
offset = i * sizeof(int);
```

Finally, add that to the base address:

```
addr = base + offset
```

so the formula is:

```
addr =  base + (c+r*w) * sizeof(int)
```