# Why say that a 2-dimensional array is a "pointer to a pointer?"

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose we have that the following 2-dimensional array:

```
int multi[3][3];
```

As I understand it, we can then say that `multi` is a "pointer to a pointer", or -- at the very least -- we can do something like the followiong:

```
int **p_p_int = multi;
```

**Question:** Why don't we say that `multi` is a "pointer to a pointer to a pointer to pointer", since `multi` points towards the address of its first element, which itself points to a pointer, which points towards the address of `multi[0][0]`, which itself points to the value of `multi[0][0]`.

This seems to be **4** objects that point (here I'm counting addresses as pointers).

Now you might say "but addresses aren't pointers, even though pointers can equal addresses", in which case it also seems weird to say that a 2-dimensional array is a "pointer to a pointer", since it's actually a pointer to an address to a pointer to an address (to a value).

I feel like I have mananaged to confuse myself quite a bit here :)

Comment: `int multi[3][3];` decayes to `int* [3]`, that's all .

Comment: Just because you can say it, doesn't make it true.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley what's wrong with that?

Comment: @DavidHaim: What's wrong with the statement *"we can then say that multi is a "pointer to a pointer""* ? It's false, namely.

Comment: oh, I thought you talked about my statement,which may be false, I don't know anymore :)

Comment: @George: Did you actually try this?: `int **p_p_int = multi;`

Comment: related/dupe: [Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: @George try something line `printf("%p\n%p", multi, &multi[0][0]);` if you want evidence beyond the documentation that `multi` really isn't an array of pointers to other arrays.

Comment: A 2D array is simply an array of arrays. Defining `int multi[3][3]` does not create any pointer objects, just an array consisting of 3 sub-arrays, each of which consists of 3 `int` objects. Evaluating the name `multi` can give you an *address* (a pointer value), but does not create a pointer object. An `int**` (pointer to pointer to `int`) cannot be used unless there is an `int*` pointer object for it to point to. Recommended reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) (it applies to C++ as well as to C).

Answer (score 2):

A 1d array converts to a pointer rather than being one — e.g. you can reassign a pointer, you cannot reassign an array.

A literal 2d array isn't stored in the way described below.

However a 2d array can be achieved by a pointer to a pointer if:

`int **array2d` is a pointer. It points to an array. That array contains pointers.

Because `array2d` points to an array of pointers, `array2d[n]` is also a pointer. But it's a pointer to an array of integers.

So that's two pointers, total.

In pseudo code, the steps to look up the item at (m, n) are:

- add m to `array2d` to index that array. Read pointer, `p` from calculated address;
- add n to `p` to index that array. Read integer from calculated address.

Comment: I think you are confusing `int *multi[]` (an array of `int*`) with `int multi[3][]` (an array of `int[3]`). In both cases, `multi[x][y]` is an `int`, but everything else is different. The second one really is a literal 2d array.

Comment: I think all that's confusing is that I've reused `multi` as my variable name. I think I've otherwise been explicit as to why a 2d array can be stored via a pointer-to-pointer but that that's not what built-in 2d arrays are.

Comment: What is `array2d`? `multi` is an array, but it contains no pointers.

Comment: @Tommy: `int multi[3][3]` *is* a 2d array. I'm not sure what you mean by "built-in 2d arrays", and your answer definitely doesn't make that clear.

Comment: @rici I'm sorry that "a literal 2d array isn't stored that way but a 2d array can be achieved by a pointer to a pointer in that: ..." is insufficiently clear for you to warrant a comment. I don't think it would be problematic for most as distinguishing that: (i) a literal 2d array is stored in some way that I'm not going to discuss; but (ii) the reason you've heard that a pointer to a pointer can be used to hold a 2d array is that you could elect to lay things out as follows. Even if they (undesirably) had to parse the sentence twice due to its backwards, unhelpful structure.

Comment: ... and I appreciate that the answer doesn't mention the fairly vague concept raised by my previous comment of "built-in 2d arrays"; that's an issue with the comment rather than the answer. I don't think it's worth addressing other than to concede that the comment isn't well-formed.

Comment: @tommy: OK, I'll yield. I don't think you've really explained to OP what is really going on, nor have you addressed directly the question, but others have, so I don't think it matters too much. There's also a zillion duplicates, and possibly one of them actually explains C arrays properly.

Comment: The question was about an actual 2D array, which is simply an array of arrays. Your answer goes off on a tangent about another way to achieve the effect of a 2D array using a different data structure. Your answer, after you edited it, is not incorrect (though you don't discuss memory allocation), but I don't believe it answers the OP's question about `int multi[3][3];`.

Comment: The question further queries why one might refer to the arrangement that he thinks a 2d array is using as merely a pointer to a pointer and not a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer. This answer applies that part of the question. As I understand it, on StackOverflow it is appropriate to post something as an answer if it contributes towards any part of the question asked, and the two people who voted upwards presumably agree.

Answer (score 2):

The job of a pointer is to point towards something. Just because something is both a pointer and points to something else doesn't make it a pointer to a pointer, unless that something else is a pointer.

So let's break this down:

> multi points towards the address of its first element,

That makes it a pointer

> which itself points to a pointer,

That makes it a pointer to a pointer.

> which points towards the address of multi[0][0],

No. It contains the address of `multi[0][0]`, it doesn't point to it.

> which itself points to the value of multi[0][0]

Well, of course. It's a pointer, pointers point to values, that's their job. That doesn't make them pointers to pointers, it makes them pointers to values.

> This seems to be 4 objects that point (here I'm counting addresses as pointers).

Sure, but two of those pointings are the very same pointing just counted twice. You say `X is a pointer that contains a value that points to something` as if that was two separate pointings. The job of a pointer is to have a value that points to something, that's what makes it a pointer in the first place. It's two ways of saying the same thing, "X is a pointer" = "X contains a value (of a type) that points to something".

Answer (score 1):

Saying that `multi` is a `pointer to a pointer` is just wrong. It is a 2D array.
`multi` can not be converted to a `**` - only to `*`

A `pointer to pointer` would obviously point to a pointer. `multi` is not doing that. You'll find an integer at that location - not a pointer - simply because `multi` is not an array of pointers. `multi[n]` may also be converted to a `*` but the converted value is not taken from a place where it was stored - it is just calculated from `multi`.

Don't think of a 2D array like:

```
int a[3];
int b[3];
int c[3];
int* x[3] = {a, b, c};
```

cause that is simply not how 2D arrays work.

All pointer values you get from a 2D array are calculated values - not stored values.

Comment: `multi` cannot be converted to `**`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: `(int**)multi` is a legal expression, but its value is meaningless.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - thanks for pointing that out as it was of cause a wrong statement - answered updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are two unrelated stuff here that you are mixing up:

1. the name of any array of the type `T[][][]...n...[]` decayes into `T*[][][]...n-1...[]` 
    for example: 
   `int arr [7]` decayes into `int* arr`
   `std::fstream arr[2][2]` decays into `std::fstream* arr[2]`

by decaying, we mean that a function which can get `T` can also accept `T'` which `T'` is the decayed type of `T`

2. you can dynamically create psuedo 2 dimentional arrays by using *pointer to pointer* and dynamic allcoation

   ```
   int** psuedeo2DimArray = new int*[10];
   for (auto i=0U;i<10;i++){
        psuedeo2DimArray[i] = new int[10];
   }
   ```

In all cases, the type of `multi` is `int[2][2]` and nothing else.