# Copy 2d int array to double pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays

So I have the following function. The function takes a target int ** double pointer and copies a source array to it.

```
void copyMatrix(int ** target, int m, int n, int source[m][n])
{
  int i,j;

  target = (int **) malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    target[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

  for(i=0; i < m; i++){
    for(j=0; j < n; j++){
     target[i][j] = source[i][j];
    }
  }
  printf("%d ", target[i][j]);
}
```

When i call printf after the for loops, i get a segfault, but if i call printf inside the for loops, it prints target[i][j] correctly. Why is this? I'm tearing my hair out over this...

Comment: What do you expect the value of `i` and `j` to be outside the loop?

Comment: You'll need to pass the pointer to your `**target`, so it becomes `***target`. And then use `*target = ...` when allocating. You're currently trying to modify the (double) pointer itself, not the value it points to.

Comment: Also look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/7307699/1746118

Comment: Though you should probably avoid possing triple dereferenced values. You can do it once as an excercise. Consider allocating `target` outside the `copyMatrix` function, or return it instead (and don't pass it). Since you have to free it outside the function as it's currently written, you better make `copyMatrix` behave like `malloc` and friends.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everyone. i think i learned more in about thirty seconds than I ever have about pointers

Comment: @Lundin i could swear it was c++. time for new glasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the loops, `i == m` and `j == n`. They both point 1 item past the max. Arrays in C are zero-indexed, so accessing `target[n][m]` of an array with size `[n][m]` will give an out-of-bounds access.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear as to why do you want to create an array of pointers first. With this approach, you end up having a problem of modifying the double pointer itself which will not reflect in the caller. You can simply alloc an array directly to store the input 2D array.

**Your code:**

```
void copyMatrix(int ** target, int m, int n, int source[m][n])
{
  int i,j;

  target = (int **) malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    target[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

  for(i=0; i < m; i++){
    for(j=0; j < n; j++){
     target[i][j] = source[i][j];
    }
  }
  printf("%d ", target[i][j]);
}
```

**Modified Code:**

```
void copyMatrix(int ** target, int m, int n, int source[m][n])
{
  int i,j;

  *target = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (m * n));


  for(i=0; i < m; i++){
    for(j=0; j < n; j++){
     (*target)[i][j] = source[i][j];
    }
  }
  printf("%d ", (*target)[i][j]);
}
```