# Changing an array value from a function in C

Tags: c

The program crashes right in the instruction mentioned in the source code (I didn't write all the code because it's too long)

```
int main()
{
char screen[24][80];

//......every thing is well until this instruction

backgrounds(5,screen);

//......the program doesn't execute the rest of the code

}
//______________________________________________________

//this is a header file

void backgrounds(int choice,char **screen)
{   
    if(choice==5)
    {
        screen[18][18]='-';
        screen[18][19]='-';
        screen[18][20]='-';
    }
}
```

Comment: A 2D array is not the same as a pointer to a pointer. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: And you ignored the compiler warnings because ... ?

Comment: also having a function in a header file is (generally) a Bad Idea(tm)

Comment: this line: `backgrounds(5,screen);` is not passing a `**screen`   Suggest the `backgrounds()` function signature be: `void backgrounds( int choice, char screen[][80] )`

Comment: @samgak I see, now I understand how it's working thank you !

Comment: @Olaf the compiler didn't mention about it

Comment: @pm100 I will look what best works for it ,@user3629249 I fixed the problem with the second code in the comment below

Comment: @heiwiper: Get a modern compiler then and enable recommended warnings.

Comment: @Olaf modem compiler ?? I'm working with GNU compiler in codeblocks 16.01

Comment: I'm pretty sure I wrote "mode**r**n" and also mentioned to enable warnings. You definitively should get a type missmatch warning.

Comment: @Olaf Ah sorry didn't read it well, and I will look at it Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char [24][80]` cannot be converted to a `char **`.

When passed to a function, an array decays into a pointer to its first element.  This is simple for a 1 dimensional array, but less so for higher dimensions.

In this case, a `char [24][80]` is an array of `char [80]`.  So passing a variable of this type to a function yields a `char (*)[80]`.

Change your function definition to either this:

```
void backgrounds(int choice,char (*screen)[80])
```

Or this:

```
void backgrounds(int choice,char screen[24][80])
```

Or you can use a variable length array for maximum flexibility:

```
void backgrounds(int choice, int x, int y, char screen[x][y])
```

Comment: "This is straightforward for a 1 dimensional array, but not for higher dimensions." - That's wrong. It is very well straight-forward: It decays to a pointer to an array of one less dimension: a 2D array decays to a pointer to a 1D array, a 3D array to a pointer to 2D array, etc. As you wrote: an array decays to a pointer to its element. An element of a (n)D-array is an (n-1)D array. With a 0D array being a single element.

Comment: @Olaf "straightforward" probably wasn't the best choice of words.  Changed to "simple".

Comment: I'm still not happy with this. Maybe I'm too deep into this, but to me it as both, straight-forward and obvious: an array always decays to a pointer to the first element. There is no exception how many dimensions. Actually the confusion is that ppl don't stop after this decaing, but think it recurses to the next dimension and so on. But that's **not** obvious to me. Anyway, I don't intend to DV for this, so feel free to ignore my comment :-)

Comment: I would just say 'do this' and have the direct [24][80] version

Comment: @pm100: Agreed with a slight modification: No magic numbers. Either a VLA with dimensions passed (most flexible) or macros with the constants.