# Why the array dont behave like excepted? C

Tags: c, arrays

In that link:
[Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays)

I saw that arrays are represented like this:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
| | | | | | | | | | | | | ..............| | | (10*6 elements of type int)
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
< first row >< second row> ...
```

Buy then I tried to do the next thing:

```
    char words[6][21];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter word number %d: \n", i + 1);
        fgets(words[i], 21, stdin);
        words[i][strcspn(words[i], "\n")] = 0;
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf("%d", (*(words + 0)));
```

As wrote in the link, if the input is:

```
123
654
555
444
888
666
```

Then the output should be '1'.
But instead, the output is the memory adress. sombody can explain me the missundersood?

Comment: Read section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: if You want `1`, `printf("%c", **words);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you wrote `printf("%d", (*(words + 0)));`

`words+0` turn into `words`, so it's like `printf("%d", *words);

`*words` is like `words[0]` that is like `&words[0][0]` that is the address that printed.

you shoud change that to what that you want to print like:

```
printf("%c", **words)
```

to print the first char. remember that your array is char[][] so print this in "%c".

Answer (score 1):

Actually `*words` is the pointer to the first line of the two dimensional array `words[][]`. Since you just want an element, you need to type `**(words + whatever)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change :

```
printf("%d", (*(words + 0)));
```

to :

```
printf("%d", words[0][0]);
```

or :

```
printf("%d", **words);
```

or finally, to a more similar version to yours :

```
printf("%d", *(words[0] + 0));
```

Keep in mind that :

```
words[i][j]
```

is ***equivalent*** to :

```
*(words[i] + j)
```

as well as to :

```
*(*(words + i) + j)
```

Based on this, you can see that your statement :

```
printf("%d", (*(words + 0)));
```

is the same as :

```
printf("%d", *words);
```

or :

```
printf("%d", words[0]);
```

which means that you print the address of the first array in `words`.

---

Also, you need to change the format specifier to `%c`, in order to specify that you print a `char` :

```
printf("%c", words[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

if we consider words[6][21]

if you want to print 1

1.you should remember it is not integer it is char so you should %c instead of %d

2. if you want to print words[0][0] equivalent word[i][j] is *(*(words+i)+j)

   so instead of writing (*(words + 0)) write *(*(words + 0))

Answer (score 0):

Your output format is incorrect.

```
printf("%d", (*(words + 0)));
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%d", *words);
```

which gives the address of the first array in the array-of-arrays.

Instead use `printf("%d", words[0][0]);` to print the first element.