# Segmantation fault when trying to access array of character pointers

Tags: c

so i've created a function that deals with a array of char pointers
by using the [] operators.
the function

```
int fetchargs(char **argv){
argv[0][0] = 'A';     
};
```

will result in segmentation fault.
i pass a array of character pointers that was initialized as follow

```
char argv[ARG_NUM][MAX_LINE];
```

trying to figure out the cause,but with not success

what might be the issuse?

Comment: `char[][]` is not the same as `char**`

Comment: `int fetchargs(char **argv){` --> `int fetchargs(int col_size, char argv[][col_size]){` , call `fetchargs(MAX_LINE, argv);`

Comment: wow! of course it's not the same..might be the hour.. char[][] is a matrix of characters

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char ** argv` is a *pointer to a pointer* of character(s) or a `double pointer`
Where as `argv[ARG_NUM][MAX_LINE]` is essentially a 2D array of characters

### Bottom line here is to Honor the Data Types

```
char argv[ARG_NUM][MAX_LINE];
.........
.........
int fetchargs(char argv[][MAX_LINE]){
  argv[0][0] = 'A'; 
  return 0;  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how you should pass it to the function because it isn't a `char **`. You have to delete the `;` after the curly bracket.

```
/*Dim is your ARG_NUM and dim2 MAX_LINE*/
int fetchargs(int dim1,int dim2,char pass[][MAX_LINE]){
    /*Some stuff*/
    return 1;
}/*You've a semicolon here*/
```