# C language pointers: int ** Vs. int (*g)[]

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

everyone.

I use Visual Studio 2013 (C++) and defined a 2d array in main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int g[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3, }, { 4, 5, 6, }, { 7, 8, 9, }, };
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

then, I defined a function in Define 1:

Define 1:

```
void print_array(int **arr, int kx, int ky)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < kx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ky; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I want to call this function from main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int g[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3, }, { 4, 5, 6, }, { 7, 8, 9, }, };

    print_array(g, 3, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

The visual studio tells me that:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'void print_array(int **,int,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [3][3]' to 'int **'
```

I also know another definition method:

Define 2

```
void print_array(int (*arr)[3], int kx, int ky)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < kx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ky; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Now it works.

My question is: I remenbered before that they (Define 1 and Define 2) worked both in old compiler, named you can pass array name as `int **` or `int (*p) []` correctly to another function. However in Visual Studio C++ it is not. Is Visual Studio C++ much stricter than other compiler ? Or I did something wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: "*you can pass array name as `int **` or `int (*p) []`*" you probably either hadn't enabled or simply ignored the other "*old*" compiler's warnings then. *Or* your memory is cheating on you ... ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I remenbered before that they (Define 1 and Define 2) worked both in old compiler,

If the memory is correct, the old compiler was broken. The code was never valid C.

You can convert an array, `int x[3]`, to a pointer, `int *p`, freely. This has always worked, and there are many cases where it happens implicitly.

However, `int (*x)[3]` is a pointer and `int **y` is a pointer, but they point to completely different types of objects! You can't convert a `int *` to a `double *` either.

You can see that `x` and `y` have different structure if you draw them out:

```
+-------------+       +-----+
| int (*x)[3] | ----> | int |
+-------------+       | --- |
                      | int |
                      | --- |
                      | int |
                      +-----+
                      | ... |

+---------+       +-------+       +-----+
| int **y | ----> | int * | ----> | int |
+---------+       +-------+       +-----+
                  |  ...  |       | ... |
```

They don't look the same at all, do they?

Comment: Thank you! Very clear explanation! I am now using the second method: int (*) [] and it fits well.

Answer (score 1):

Array and pointer conversion can only be done on the 1st level, so `int*` and `int[]` fit well into each other, but not `int**` and `int[][]`.

Actually, `int**` (can be converted to `int(*)[]`) points to an array of pointers, **each of which can point to different locations**, but obviously the sub-arrays of a 2D array can't. That's the problem you're facing.

Comment: Please, what do you want to express here: "*can be converted to `int(*)[]`*"?

Answer (score 1):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type “N-element array of `T`” will be converted (“decay”) to an expression of type “pointer to `T`”, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you call `print_array( g, 3, 3 );`, the expression `g` has type “3-element array of `T`”, where `T` is “3-element of `int`”.  So `g` will “decay” to type “pointer to `T`”, or “pointer to 3-element of `int`”, or `int (*)[3]`.  That’s why your second definition works.

Here’s a handy table to help remember some of these rules:

```
Type            Decays to
————            —————————
T [N]           T *
T [M][N]        T (*)[N]
T [L][M][N]     T (*)[M][N]
```