# Pass fixed sized array to a function with pointer argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm wondering is there a way to get the following code to work, or do I have to create a new copy of the function for fixed sizes? If so how can I have a generic function for fixed sizes.

```
void prettyPrintMatrix_float(float **matrix, int rows, int cols){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            printf("%10.3f", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

float ppArray[4][10] = {0.0f};
prettyPrintMatrix_float(ppArray, 4, 10);
```

Gives an error `Access violation reading location 0xFFFFF...`.

Comment: BTW, `float[4][10]` doesn't decay to `float**` but `(*float)[4]`. That is the reason you are getting a violation.

Comment: The problem is not passing a fixed-size array to a function, it's passing a two-dimensional array as a pointer to a pointer.  `float **` is not `float[][]`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I got that from the warning. But it shouldn't matter in the end because both are saved in the same way in the memory ie as a long 1D array of pointer, right? So is there a way to get around it?

Comment: No, a `float **` would be a pointer to a pointer, which could be an array of arrays.  A `float *` could technically point to your matrix, but the issue is that you are now dealing with a decayed pointer; one that does not know how many columns would be in the matrix, so it would not know how to index in two dimension, it would only know how to index in one dimension.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons What does an array of arrays in look like in the memory? I thought it was just a list of pointer each pointer pointing to each row's first element.

Comment: It is.  However a two-dimensional array is not an array of pointers.  A two-dimensional array is a series of values stored contiguously in memory rather than each row being stored in separate locations.  A two-dimensional array simply needs a little math to calculate where the start of each row is, while an array of arrays needs to follow a pointer to each row.  The way they are used looks similar, but they are not interchangeable.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Ok. That actually makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: No, a `float[4][10]` in memory is simply 40 floats in a row. There are no pointers.  However, the array can *decay* to a `float(*)[4]`, which is a pointer to an unknown amount of `float[4]`, each of which is 4 floats in a row. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: There is about a zillion duplicate questions in there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler supports Variable Length Arrays then you can define the function like

```
void prettyPrintMatrix_float( int rows, int cols, float matrix[rows][cols] ){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            printf("%10.3f", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can define the function like

```
void prettyPrintMatrix_float(const float *matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("%10.3f", matrix[i * cols + j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
prettyPrintMatrix_float( ( const float * )ppArray, 4, 10);
```

Comment: I wish. But it does not. So I can't do this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @user14492 Huh, are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: No C99 compiler.

Comment: @user14492 I could be wrong here, but i'm pretty sure VLA's are part of the/mandated by the C99 standard

Comment: @George you are correct, C99 standard mandates Variable Length Arrays be supported.

Comment: It must be some other one because when I try to do this I get: `Expected constant expression` error when compiling.

Comment: are you passing in the `-std=c99` flag?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Sorry I don't know. I didn't set up the project.

Answer (score 0):

If Variable Length Arrays are not available to you, and your function will be taking in matrices of varying dimensions, then you're function will have to treat it as a one-dimensional array and manually do the math for calculating where the start of each row is.  Something like this:

```
void prettyPrintMatrix_float(float *matrix, int rows, int cols){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            printf("%10.3f", matrix[i * sizeof(float) + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

float ppArray[4][10] = {0.0f};
prettyPrintMatrix_float(&ppArray[0][0], 4, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution with templates

```
template<int rows, int cols>
void prettyPrintMatrix_float(float (&matrix)[rows][cols])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("%10.3f", matrix[i,j]);
            // Or
            //printf("%10.3f", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: *Just another solution with templates*  For C?!?!