# Constructor won't take array initialized with new, as a parameter

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, constructor, new-operator

Suppose i have created a constructor that takes an int m[5][5].Whenever i initialize an array in main like:(int k[5][5];) and pass it as an argument to the constructor it works fine.Yet,i have tried allocating the 2-d array as below:

```
  int **d=new int*[5];
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   d[i]=new int[5];  }

    //5x5 matrix
```

and the constructor won't take the array as a parameter.
Why is this happening?

Comment: "Why is this happening?" have you tried to read what compiler tells you? Anyway please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Note the existence of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). I.e. `std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int d[5][5];
```

does not define a double pointer although the syntax may lead you to think so. See [Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Thanks so much,i understood where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to pointers each carrying an array is not a 2D array, so d[n][m] is not **d, although you may be treating both with the same way to get values from them as follows: d[i][j].

So either make your constructor as follows:

```
className(int **d);
```

or just pass a normal 2D array and your constructor will be like this:

```
className(int d[5][5]);
```