# Regarding binary predicate Compare

Tags: c++, c++11, compare

My reference is to the binary predicate `Compare comp` expected in the overload of [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) etc.:

The description reads:

> The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the
>   following:
>
> bool pred(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
>
> While the signature does not need to have const &, the function must
>   not modify the objects passed to it and must be able to accept all
>   values of type (possibly const) Type1 and Type2 regardless of value
>   category (thus, Type1 & is not allowed, nor is Type1 unless for Type1
>   a move is equivalent to a copy (since C++11)).

I am a bit confused by the following part of the description (which appears to be contradictory?):

> ...the function must not modify the objects passed to it and must be
>   able to accept all values of type (possibly const) Type1 and Type2
>   regardless of value category (thus, Type1 & is not allowed, nor is
>   Type1 unless for Type1 a move is equivalent to a copy (since C++11))

If the function should accept all value categories, why is `Type1` not allowed? Also, why should a `move` be equivalent to `copy` for `Type1` to be allowed, since C++11?

Comment: The "all value categories" part refers to the types of the arguments supplied by the caller, while "not allowed" refers to the types of the parameters in the function declaration. There is not a direct conflict here.

Comment: I believe you oversaw the last part: _nor is Type1 **unless for Type1 a move is equivalent to a copy** (since C++11)_ This is for example true for primitive types as well as raw pointers. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56681848/7478597)