# How to pass statically allocated 2D array to a function in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, function-parameter

I am modifying some code to move away from using dynamic memory allocation because it will be embedded on a system.  I am statically allocating memory for my objects then assigning pointers to these.
I need to be able to pass pointers to 2D arrays to functions, but am finding that this is not working, where it was with dynamically allocated arrays.

Here is some example code.  Passing the dynamically allocated array x to my function works no problem.

However it fails with the statically allocated array, y in the function "func" where it tries writing to the first element of the array "array[i][j] = i * j".  The error message is "Access violating writing location 0x00000000.  My question is why, and what I can do to resolve this?

```
void func(int** array, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)array[i][j] = i * j;
}

static int y[ROWS][COLS];

int main()
{
    int rows, cols, i;
    int **x;
    rows = ROWS; cols = COLS;
    // Dynamic allocation of X:
    x = malloc(rows * sizeof *x);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        x[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof *x[i]);
    }
    // The following works no problem:
    func(x, rows, cols);
    // However doing it with the statically allocated array fails.
    func(y, rows, cols);

    /* deallocate the array */
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        free(x[i]);
    }
    free(x);
}
```

Comment: These 2 are not interchangeable.

Comment: The problem rather is how you allocate dynamically

Comment: "It fails" is not a very good problem description. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: in any case: please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3912959/918959 it detalis everything.

Comment: Also you should have gotten a diagnostics message from your C compiler.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I did give the error messsage.  I have added to say where exactly this happens.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It compiles no problem.   The error message I quote in the question is the runtime exception.

Comment: @bgarrood then your compiler is broken. Which compiler this is btw?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The duplicate you point me to I have already read and is where my question came from.  Why does passing a dynamically allocated array work when a statically allocated one does not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202379/discussion-between-bgarrood-and-antti-haapala).

Comment: @bgarrood because the type is **wrong**. The C compiler **must** produce a diagnostics message for that.

Comment: I think; when marking as duplicate, sometimes people take action too fast, w/o giving enough time for problem explanation. This question is one of them which needs some more explanation. Taking a glance at the code, it is hard to deduce the real user attempt: Does the user try to create a two dimensional `m` by `n` int array, which can be achieved like [`int *arr = malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));`] or an array of pointers pointing to different rows of an array like [`int **arr = malloc(m * sizeof(uintptr_t);`] and then creating m times [`*(arr + i) = malloc(n * sizeof(int));`]?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, the duplicate thread does not explain the current problem, in my opinion. Also, a standard compiler like GCC gives a warning for this, but not an error (obviously a developper should care about any warning).

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean the warning stuff was solved in chat.

Comment: Well it is a pity, since the answer is not that obvious and it would have been interesting for many people (much more than the average basic C question published in stackoverflow)

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean the question has been asked over and over again over many times. This particular problem is almost weekly, I'd say. The problem here was that OP didn't see the compiler diagnostics.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean here, more duplicates. Notice that all of them have a shorter code and they get to the point.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean the point in closing as a duplicate is to **ensure** that the question gets only the **best** answers, if the question is closed as a duplicate then *all* the answers will be located in the *one* place. Anyone who has this question should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7307699/918959) for example, not some inferior answer that has been drafted specifically for this piece of code.

Comment: Yes, the answer you're pointing to is indeed a real duplicate.

Comment: The problem of course is that there are **too many inferior questions** already that finding the ones with the *best answers* takes time. One needs to bookmark all these and remember the titles (I didn't remember that one).