# How does *(&arr + 1) - arr give the length in elements of array arr?

Tags: c++, arrays

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
   int  arr[5] = {5, 8, 1, 3, 6};
   int len = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
   cout << "The length of the array is: " << len;
   return 0;
}
```

For the code above, I don't quite understand what these two pieces of codes are doing:

```
*(&arr + 1)
```

and

```
*(&arr)
&arr
```

Could someone explains? Because when I run the following two codes, I get the same output for the following:

`&arr` (I think this point to the address of the first element of arr)

`*(&arr)` then I don't quite understand what this do, what does the symbol `*` do to `&arr` (i.e. to the address here)?, because the two outputs are the same when I run them

and finally what is it exactly happening when an integer say 1 is added to the address by this code here:
`&arr + 1`

Comment: `*(&arr + 1) ` invokes *undefined behavior*. This code does not calculate the length of an array, it's just broken

Comment: but how comes this gives the length: *(&arr + 1) - arr

Comment: *Undefined behavior* means that anything can happen. Including accidentally the result you expected. Though that might just be on your computer and compiler

Comment: There is certainly more to that than just undefined code. There should be a technical reason for this, which I am currently trying to understand.

Comment: Please forget this trick as quickly as possible. Use the canonical `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)` instead.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Or even better: `std::size(arr)`. OP wants to understand how it works so I don't think this is something he actually uses.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, that's even better in C++. The `sizeof` approach works both in C and C++, though.

Answer (score 5):

This is a mine field, but I'll give it a try:

- `&arr` returns a pointer to an `int[5]`
- `+ 1` steps the pointer one `int[5]`
- `*(&arr + 1)` dereferences the result back to an `int(&)[5]`
  I don't know if this causes undefined behavior, but if it doesn't, the next step will be:
- `*(&arr + 1) - arr` does pointer arithmetics after the two `int[5]`'s have decayed to `int` pointers, returning the diff between the two `int` pointers, which is `5`.

---

Rewritten to make it a bit clearer:

```
int  arr[5] = {5, 8, 1, 3, 6};

int (*begin_ptr)[5] = &arr + 0;     // begin_ptr is a  int(*)[5]
int (*end_ptr)[5]   = &arr + 1;     // end_ptr is a    int(*)[5]

// Note:
//       begin_ptr + 1        ==  end_ptr
//       end_ptr - begin_ptr  ==  1

int (&begin_ref)[5] = *begin_ptr;   // begin_ref is a  int(&)[5]
int (&end_ref)[5]   = *end_ptr;     // end_ref is a    int(&)[5]   UB here?

auto len = end_ref - begin_ref; // the array references decay into int*
std::cout << "The length of the array is: " << len << '\n'; // 5
```

I'll leave the question if it's UB or not open but referencing an object before the referenced storage has been allocated *does* look a bit suspicious.

Comment: constructing a pointer to one past the last element is fine so `&arr + 1` is ok. Dereferencing it is UB so `*(&arr + 1)` is not ok.

Comment: @bolov Yeah, I was staring at what I wrote and tried to reason with myself about it. It's still not accessing memory, it's only the type that changes. Does that matter?

Comment: Well, it is undefined behavior, you are dereferencing a pointer to array by using indirection operator.

Comment: @SergeyA Do you mean that `*(&arr + 0)` would be UB too or is it that it's dereferenced to an `int[5]` _one past the end_ that makes it UB?

Comment: Yes, you are dereferencing one past the end, which is not allowed. I am trying really hard now to come up with the code exploiting the same technique, but can't find any. I am on the verge of asking a language lawyer question.

Comment: This code is not actually *dereferencing* past the end of `arr` itself, it is *creating* a pointer to the end of `arr`, but it is not dereferencing that pointer to access the memory of `arr` itself. Now granted, the code is using a temporary pointer, treating the whole `arr` as a single-element array for purposes of the `+1` arithmetic, and then dereferencing that pointer, but because the backing memory is another array, and this code is just manipulating pointers, not actually accessing any memory, I'm not sure that the behavior is actually undefined...

Comment: Asked The Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238781/forcing-a-decay-of-the-array-for-the-lack-of-better-title

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that's where my thoughts went with this. Let's home SergeyA's `language-lawyer` question sorts it out.

Comment: ...Just as it is perfectly legal to increment a pointer well beyond the bounds of an array, as long as it is decremented back into bounds before being dereferenced.

Comment: I will explain why I think it is undefined in my question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau hm... It is way more complicated than I thought. Apparently there was language considered to explicitly allow the indirection through such pointers (including null pointer) but it was never adopted. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232. Let's see what my answer will fetch.

Comment: Hello Ted, for your first highlight (i.e. &arr) when you said it "return pointer to an int[5]", could you explain what is this "int[5]"? is this an empty array of integer of length 5?

Comment: And for your second highlight (i.e. +1), could you explains what you mean when you said "steps the pointer one int[5]", what does it mean by "steps the pointer one"? sorry could you elaborate a little bit more. Thank you.

Comment: @john_w I'll try to illustrate it better where I've given the variables clear types. [example @ godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zSv54h) (updated)

Comment: @john_w see the answer I just posted

Comment: @john_w I put the relevant parts from my earlier godbolt example into the answer to try to clarify it a bit too.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following facts:

- When you increment/decrement a pointer by an integral value `X`, the value of the pointer is increased/decreased by `X` times the number of bytes of the type the pointer is pointing at.
- When you subtract 2 pointers of the same type, the result is the difference between their held addresses, divided by the number of bytes of the type being pointed at.
- When you refer to an array by its name alone, it *decays* into a pointer to the array's 1st element.

The type of your `arr` variable is `int[5]`, ie an array of 5 `int`s.  `&arr` returns an `int[5]*` pointer to `arr` (technically, it is actually written like `int(*)[5]`, but lets not worry about that here, for simplicity).  Lets call this pointer `temp` below.

Then, the `+ 1` increments the value of `temp` by 1 `int[5]` element. In other words, the address stored in `temp` is increased by `1 * sizeof(int[5])`, or `1 * (sizeof(int) * 5)`, number of bytes.  This effectively gives you an `int[5]*` pointer to the end of `arr` (ie, to `&arr[5]`).  No `int[5]` element *physically* exists at that memory address, but it is legal to create a pointer to it, for purposes of pointer arithmetic.

Dereferencing `temp` gives you a reference to an `int[5]` at the end of `arr`. That reference *decays* into an `int*` pointer when passed to `operator-`.

In `- arr`, the reference to `arr` *decays* into an `int*` pointer to `arr[0]` when passed to `operator-`.

Thus, given this code:

`int len = *(&arr + 1) - arr;`

Which is effectively the same as this:

`int len = &arr[5] - &arr[0];`

Which is effectively the same as this:

`int len = (<address of arr[5]> - <address of arr[0]>) / sizeof(int);`

Thus, the result is 5.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
int  arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; 
int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

Here the pointer arithmetic does its part. We don’t need to explicitly convert each of the locations to character pointers.

`&arr` ==> Pointer to an array of 6 elements.
         [See this for difference between &arr
          and arr]

`(&arr + 1)` ==> Address of 6 integers ahead as
               pointer type is pointer to array
               of 6 integers.

`*(&arr + 1)` ==> Same address as (&arr + 1), but 
                type of pointer is "int *".

`*(&arr + 1) - arr` ==> Since *(&arr + 1) points 
                   to the address 6 integers
                   ahead of arr, the difference
                   between two is 6.

Comment: hello, for your first highlight, could you provide the link for "this"?  And for your second highlight, could you explain what you means by "Address of 6 integers ahead"?  what does it mean 6 integers ahead (ahead of what sorry, what is the starting place to count from)?

Comment: @john_w Ahead of the beginning address of `arr`

Comment: @john_w adding 1 to a pointer actually adds the number of total bits that it points to.. so  `(&arr + 1)` will add 6 bits (assuming `int` to be of size 1).

Answer (score 1):

&arr ==> Pointer to an array of n elements.
(&arr + 1) ==> Address of 6 integers ahead as
pointer type is pointer to array
of n integers.

*(&arr + 1) ==> Same address as (&arr + 1), but
type of pointer is "int *".

*(&arr + 1) - arr ==> Since *(&arr + 1) points
to the address n integers
ahead of arr, the difference
between two is n.

1. (&arr + 1) points to the memory address right after the end of the array.
2. *(&arr + 1) simply casts the above address to an int *.
3. Subtracting the address of the start of the array, from the address of the end of the array,​ gives the length of the array.

MORE ON THIS...>>>>>>>>>>>

The trick is to use the expression (&arr)[1] - arr to get the array arr size. Both arr and &arr points to the same memory location, but they both have different types.

1. arr has the type int* and decays into a pointer to the first element of the
   array. Hence, any knowledge about the size of the array is gone.
2. &arr results in a pointer of type int (*)[n], i.e., a pointer to an array of
   n ints. So, &arr points to the entire array and *(&arr + 1) (or &arr)[1])
   points to the next byte after the array.

This works because of the way pointer arithmetic works in C. We know that a pointer to int is advanced by sizeof(int) when incrementing by 1. Similarly, a pointer to int[n] is advanced by sizeof(int[n]), which is the size of the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am too late to join the discussion, but I think this is a good question and it deserve a more thorough answer.

I originally see the op snippet at [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-find-the-length-of-an-array-in-cpp)

There are total 4 operations here.

What `&arr` actually does is to dynamically creating a 2d array, with its first dimension equal to 1, and get the pointer point to the head of this 2d array.
If you are not familiar with the 2d array, Shahbaz have introduce it very well at
[Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays)
In particular, it is the structure of `array2` in the post, and the pointer point to this newly created 2d array has type `int (*)[5]`

The `+1` in `&arr+1` do the pointer arithmetic on it first dimension. Recalled that the first dimension is just 1. This is exactly why the `(&arr + 1)` points to the memory address right after the end of the original array.

The `*` in `*(&arr + 1)` convert the 2d array pointer (which has type `int (*)[5]`) back to one dimensional array pointer (which has type `int*`).

Finally the `- arr` in `*(&arr + 1) - arr` is a pointer subtraction. According to the standard (`N1570`):

> 6.5.6 Additive operators
> ....
> <sup>9</sup> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements.

One final question arised, In the discussion of [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)
We know that the `sizeof` method only work for arrays on stack, but how about this method? Unfortunately, this method also work on stack only. If you receive the pointer of array inside a function, the array size information is loss and you have no way to dynamically create a 2d array for it. The pointer arithmetic follows will simply fall apart.