# Forcing a decay of the array (for the lack of better title)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Inspired by this question: [How does *(&arr + 1) - arr give the length in elements of array arr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237796/how-does-arr-1-arr-give-the-length-in-elements-of-array-arr)

The following code will calculate the length of an array, albeit invoking undefined behavior:

```
int  arr[] = {5, 8, 1, 3, 6};
size_t len = *(&arr + 1) - &arr[0]; // len is 5
```

I believe, that by dereferencing the (&arr + 1) we are triggering undefined behavior. However, the only reason we are doing this is to immediately decay the result into `int*`, pointing to one element after the last one in original array. Since we do not dereference this pointer, we are well in defined zone.

The question thus is following: is there a way to decay into `int*` without dereferencing the undereferencable pointer and staying defined?

P.S. Mandatory disclaimer: yes, I can calculate the size of an array with `sizeof` operator and division. This is not the point of the question.

*EDIT:*
I am now less sure that the indirection itself is undefined. I have found http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232 and from it looks it seems like there was an attempt to legalize the indirection per se, but I was not able to find any wording to this effect in actual standard.

Comment: You could do it in C++14 using `reinterpret_cast<int*>(&arr + 1)`, but this isn't possible anymore in C++17.

Comment: If you simply convert to `uinptr_t` types, the conversion to `int*` wouldn't be needed and the size could found with: `size_t len =  ((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&arr + 1) - reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&arr[0]) ) / sizeof arr[0] );`. This is obviously not quite "equivalent" to the original...

Comment: @usr I think that's not guaranteed to work by the standard, but in practice it most likely will.

Comment: @Brian I believe the conversion to uintptr_t is implementation-defined.

Comment: @usr You're right. So it's guaranteed to work if your implementation says that it does something sane.

Comment: Note: it is better to calculate array size with `::std::size` rather than with `sizeof` and division.

Comment: This doesn't mean much, but Clang diagnoses it as UB in `constexpr` context, while GCC and MSVC don't. See https://godbolt.org/z/9oWef6. But GCC and MSVC seem to not correctly diagnose illegal pointer arithmetic (e.g. adding `2` instead of `1`) either.

Comment: size_t arr_len = &(&arr)[1][0] - &(&arr)[0][0];
What about this ?

Comment: @Strongwill `(&arr)[1]` is equivalent to `*(&arr + 1)`.

Comment: Would this be a crystal clear UB: `int (&end_ref)[5] = *(&arr + 1); auto len = end_ref - arr;` to not force the reference decaying into a pointer immediately? "_A reference is required to be initialized to refer to a valid object or function_"  (possibly after the referred object's storage has been allocated but before it's actually constructed, if I understand it correctly). Is a reference to something before its storage has been allocated different than a pointer to something before its storage has been allocated? If it is, perhaps the answer can be found there? (i'm  not a language-lawyer)

Answer (score 2):

What is known as "decay" is "array-to-pointer conversion" in standardese, and it is clear that what you ask is impossible:

[[conv.array]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.array)

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”

There can be no [lvalue](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#1.1) referring to a non-existent array, and a rvalue (not converted from the lvalue) can't refer to the same array.

---

Now to clarify a few points:

- `&arr + 1` is a [pointer pass the end of an object](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3), and indirection is [defined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary.op#1) only on pointers to actual objects. The active issue is about null pointers, which isn't relevant to pointers pass the end of an object.
- Pointer arithmetic is only [defined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#5) on objects within the same array, even if you had `int arr[2][5];`, `*(&arr + 1)` decayed as `int*` is *not* considered part of the array `arr[0]`, and so `&arr[1][0] - &arr[0][0]` is still undefined.

Comment: @M.M Sorry, I meant that using them is undefined. I removed it since it's kinda hard to phrase in a short sentence.