# Different implementations of begin() and end() of a container

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I am practicing implementing containers. My goal is to define the iterators `begin()` and `end()`
so that I can have loops in the form of `for(auto x : v)`. My container looks like this:

```
class Vector{
public:
    Vector(initializer_list<double> numbers){
        sz = numbers.size();
        elem = new double[sz];
        int i = 0;
        for (auto it = numbers.begin(); it!=numbers.end(); ++it)
            elem[i++] = *it;
    }
    ~Vector(){delete [] elem;}
    double* begin();
    double* end();
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz;
    
};
```

**Option 1**

This is how I have defined the iterators (and they work perfectly fine in my test cases)

```
double* Vector::begin(){
    return elem;
}

double* Vector::end(){
    return &elem[sz];
}
```

**Option 2**

This is how they are defined in *A Tour of C++*

```
double* Vector::begin(){
    return &elem[0];
}

double* Vector::end(){
    return &elem[0]+sz;
}
```

**My question**

As far as I can see both options work fine (assuming the container is non-empty). Does Option 2 have any advantages compared to Option 1 (and vice versa)? I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `double* Vector::end() { return elem + sz; }`?

Comment: On a side note, your `Vector` class is violating the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) by not implementing/deleting a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, and a move constructor and move assignment operator. Other than as a learning experience, there is no real benefit to implementing a custom `Vector` class rather than using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 9):

While `&elem[sz]` and `&elem[0]+sz` will wind up giving you the same result on most/all systems, the first is actually undefined behavior.  When you do

```
&elem[sz]
```

you are actually doing

```
&*(elem +sz)
```

and that `*`, the dereference, is to an element that doesn't exist.  That is undefined behavior per the C++ standard.

With

```
&elem[0]+sz
```

you get a pointer to the first element which is legal provided the pointer points to an actual array, and then you advance it to be one past the end.  This is a legal and a correct way to get the end iterator provided `elem` is not null and points to a valid array.

---

Another way to do this is to just use

```
return elem + sz;
```

as it doesn't require any dereferencing.

Comment: "*With `&elem[0]+sz` you get a pointer to the first element which is legal*" - provided `elem` is not null and `sz` is not 0, otherwise `elem[0]` aka `*elem` would be dereferencing a non-existing element.  `return elem + sz;` is preferred in this situation, no dereferencing occurs at all.

Comment: I may be mistaken about this, but I seem to remember reading somewhere that the spec specifically says that `&*` is a no-op. Though perhaps that's C rather than C++?

Comment: @templatetypedef I haven't seen anything in the C++ standard about it being a non-op.  A goo compiler will make it one, but I don't believe it is guaranteed.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'd expect even a bad compiler to figure that one out.  But I wouldn't consider it guaranteed unless someone can quote the standard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Goood points.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @templatetypedef [This](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op) is the section that covers `*` and `&` for the purposes of this question and no where does it say doing `&*` is a non-op so at best it is a compiler optimization.

Comment: There was also a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61238068/7582247) touching this and a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238781/forcing-a-decay-of-the-array-for-the-lack-of-better-title) regarding whether `double& endref = &elem[sz];` is actually UB if `endref` is never dereferenced but only has its address taken. Neither got a definite answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Interesting.  The more I look at the text, the more it puzzles me as well.  `*` says it needs to be a pointer to an object type, not a object.  The only other thing I can find is *Otherwise, if the operand is an lvalue of type T* from [expr.unary.op] ad I'm not sure if *is an lvalue of type T* applies to the hypothetical end object.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I found it very interesting too. I read about [Access outside of lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Access_outside_of_lifetime) to see if there is some support for creating a reference to an "object" before the storage of the object has been allocated ... but I failed. The very first sentence seems to imply that storage must be allocated first.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these options work, and I would be astonished if the compiler didn't generate equivalent code for each version.

I actually prefer your implementation of `begin`, since if `elem` is a pointer, then `&elem[0]` is redundant compared to `elem`.

Another option: for `end`, you could do something like

```
return begin() + size();
```

assuming that you have a `size()` member function. This doesn't require any addresses to be taken and more directly says "the position that's `size()` steps down from where `begin()` points." But that's just my opinion. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Inside of `end()`, `return elem + sz;` would be cleaner, and avoid any unnecessary function calls.

Comment: The advice I've gotten over the years has been to use public interfaces when possible in class implementations, with the idea of making the class easier to edit / modify in the future and to clarify intent. (I think I originally saw that in "Effective C++.") But perhaps this isn't as standard as I thought it was?