# C++ Call string into function?

Tags: c++

Not sure how to exactly explain this, sorry. I'm creating a function to find the first instance of a char in an array built by a given string. I have the function to create an array from the string and loop through the array, but not sure how to put it the array into the find function.

the tester is built like

```cpp
stringName("Test test test");

stringName.find("e",0);  //where 0 is the starting position, so it would return 1.
```

```cpp
int SuperString::find(char c, int start) {
// put array grabber thing here
size = *(&data + 1) - data;
    for(int i = start; i < size ; i++){
        if(data[i] == c){
            return i;
            }
    }
   return -1;
   
    }
```

This is what I have to make the string into an array.

```cpp
SuperString::SuperString(std::string str) {
    size = str.size();
    data = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data[i] = str.at(i);
    }

}
```

This is probably something easy I'm missing, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Both kinds of string in C++ can be directly treated like arrays.

Comment: Use `std::string` as the parameter type? Like you did in the constructor?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The parameters to `find()` are what to find and where to start; it's a class so it's already holding the string and doesn't need it passed.

Comment: `"e"` is not a character.  You likely meant `'e'`.

Comment: `"e"` is a `const char[2]`, `'e'` is a `char`. Have you tried `stringName.find('e', 0)`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But I am seeing that the `data` member throws away a perfectly good `std::string` to improperly manage a heap-allocated C-string. They don't allow space for the null character.

Comment: Also just make `data` itself a `std::string` instead of making it a `char*`, you're almost certainly going to have weird headaches caused by that. You can index into a string using `operator[]` the same way as with a character array, but it introduces fewer opportunities for error.

Comment: The question and code are demonstrating some foundational gaps in OOP. [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to the good list.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string literal, specifically a `const char[2]`, where a single `char` is expected.  Use `'e'` instead of `"e"`:

```cpp
stringName.find('e', 0);
```

More importantly, `size = *(&data + 1) - data;` will only work when `data` is a (reference to a) fixed array (see [How does *(&arr + 1) - arr give the length in elements of array arr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237796/)).  It will not work when `data` is a pointer to an array, as it is in your case since you are allocating the array with `new char[]`. You will have to keep track of the array's `size` separately, which you appear to be doing, except that you are not actually using the `size` you obtained in the `SuperString` constructor.  Just get rid of the line in `find()` that is trying to re-calculate `size`, use the value you already have:

```cpp
int SuperString::find(char c, int start) {
    // size = *(&data + 1) - data; // <-- GET RID OF THIS
    for(int i = start; i < size; ++i){
        if (data[i] == c){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That being said, Your `SuperString` class can be greatly simplified if you just make its `data` member be a `std::string` instead of  `char*`, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

class SuperString {
private:
    std::string data;
    ...
public:
    SuperString(const std::string &str);
    int find(char c, int start = 0);
    ...
};

SuperString::SuperString(const std::string &str) : data(str) {
}

int SuperString::find(char c, int start) {
    return (int) data.find(c, start);
}
```