# Why can I cast from int** (as a 2 dimension array) to int*?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote the code -

```
int arr2d[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
int * arr = (int*)arr2d;
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("%d  ", arr[i]);
}
```

The output was as if I printed every element in the arrays in arr2d, nothing out of the ordinary.
Why is that so?

Comment: can you show the output ?

Comment: Why do you *want* to cast?

Comment: @MickaelB. the output is "1  2  3  4"

Comment: There is no `int**` anywhere in your code! The 2-D array `arr2d` decays to a *single* pointer to its first element, and its elements are stored in a contiguous block of memory.

Comment: And for this kind of declaration using `int[2][2]`, in the memory it is not stored as multidimentional array, but the elements are stored "inline". So if you increment after the first "row", you'll reach the second "row"

Comment: @wildplasser in the course i take they showed this casting, and it's actually a part of a bigger question. it doesn't work when the 2 dimensional array is composed out of pointers, and i have to understand why.

Comment: `int *p; p = &arr2d[0][0];` would do the same, without the need for a cast, and without the `&array` decaying to a pointer to its first element. (which is an int, not a pointer)

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I cast from int** (as a 2 dimension array) to int*?

You have a misunderstanding.  **Arrays are not pointers**.  They do *decay* to pointers in most contexts, but that's a question of *evaluation*, not nature.  Accordingly, 2D arrays are arrays of arrays, not arrays of pointers.  Thus, they do not decay to pointers to pointers, but rather pointers to arrays.  There is no `int**` involved anywhere in your code.

Given this declaration:

> ```
> int arr2d[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
> ```

The relevant pointer assignment you can perform without a cast is

```
int (*arr2d_ptr)[2];

arr2d_ptr = arr2d;  // arr2d is not a pointer, but it does decay to one in this expression
```

`arr2d_ptr` is a pointer to a two-element array of `int`.  The assignment makes it point to the first element of `arr2d`.  If you convert that to type `int *`, then the result points to the first `int` in the array to which `arr2d_ptr` points.  For example,

```
int *ip = (int *) arr2d_ptr;
```

That's natural, because that `int` is exactly the first part of the array.  You can access it by index as `ip[0]` or `*ip`.  And you can access the second `int` in that array as `ip[1]`.

I guess the other facet of the question is about the expressions `ip[2]` and `ip[3]`.  Arrays are contiguous sequences of elements.  Arrays of arrays are not special in this regard: they are contiguous sequences of (smaller) arrays.  Thus, the layout of your `arr2d` is like this:

```
array..|array..|
```

. If you overlay the layout of each of the member arrays then you get this:

```
int|int|int|int|
```

, which is exactly the same as the layout of a one-dimensional array of four `int`.  This is why you can access all four `int`s by indexing `ip` (or `arr` in your example code).

**Fun fact**: because expressions of array type decay to pointers, you don't need a cast here.  You could instead *dereference* `arr2d_ptr` to form an expression designating the first element of the 2D array, which is a 1D array, and let that decay to a pointer:

```
int *ip2 = *arr2d_ptr;
```

or, equivalently,

```
int *ip3 = *arr2d;
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are stored in memory as if it was a linear array. That's why you can access them like that.

> It doesn't work when the 2 dimensional array is composed out of pointers, and I have to understand why.

If you are working with an array of pointers you'll have to use a pointer to pointer, aka, double pointer.

It seems logic that if you want a pointer to access elements in an array of pointers you'll need a pointer to pointer.

```
//...
int *arr2d[2][2];
int **arr = (int**)arr2d;
//...
```

If you want to use it as a 2D array, which is what you would want in most cases, you can use:

[Live sample](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/AbsoluteEminentWebsites)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int arr2d[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

    int(*arr)[2] = arr2d; //pointer to 2d array with 2 columns

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            printf("%d  ", arr[i][j]); //use it as if it were a 2d array
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

A double pointer is not to be confused with a 2D array, these are different things, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays) has a nice explanation of what each of these mean.

Answer (score 0):

In memory, the array `char a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}` looks likes this:

`[(1)(2)(3)(4)]`

with `()` representing a byte of memory and `[]` hinting you where the array begins/ends.

The array `char a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` looks like this in memory:

`[[(1)(2)][(3)(4)]]`

See, there is no difference, as `[]` don't really exist in memory, they are just hints I used in my reply. Effectively, if you don't know anything about the arrays and just look at the content of the raw bytes in memory, you'll see:

`(1)(2)(3)(4)`

in **both** cases.

Thus instead of creating an array `a[Xmax][Ymax]` and accessing the elements using `a[x][y]`, you can as well create the array as `b[Xmax * Ymax]` and access the elements using `b[x * Xmax + y]`, as that's in fact what happens behind the scenes anyway.

And in C, you can always turn an array reference into a pointer, as an array reference is a reference to a memory location where an array is located and a pointer is a reference to a memory location (regardless if an array is located there or not). So

```
int a[5] = { ... };
int * b = a;
```

works as `a` is a reference to an int array, which are just several int values stored in memory, and `b` is a pointer to a memory location where an int value is stored. Well, at the address where the array `a` starts, an int value **is** stored, so this assignment is perfectly correct.

And `m[3]` just means "*increase the memory address `m` references three times by the size of the value type `m` references and fetch the value from that address*". And that works and returns the expected value, no matter if `m` is a pointer or an array reference. So while this syntax is actually intended for array access, it also works with pointers.

The syntax for a pointer would actually be `*(m + 3)`, which means "*increase the pointer address three times by the size of the value type it points to and then fetch the value from that address*". Yet, just in the first case, this syntax would work with an array reference as well, since an array reference can always become a pointer when required.