# Problem "note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[200]’"

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

In my program I declared the following:

```
char S[1000][200];
```

an array of strings, and have a function like this:

```
char** buscar_str(char **S){.......}
```

But when I try this:

```
buscar_str(S);
```

I get the mentioned error `note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[200]`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) Only the first level of indirection is converted to a pointer. E.g. `char S[1000][200];` on access is converted to `char (*S)]200];` (a *pointer-to-array* of `char[200]`). `char **` is a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not an immediate way to reconcile this. Given `char S[1000][200]`, `S` is 200,000 bytes of memory organized into 1000 arrays of 200 `char`. But the routine `buscar_str` declared with `char **buscar_str(char **S)` wants a pointer to one or more pointers to `char`. You do not have any pointers to `char` in `S`. You can give one, such as `&S[0][0]`, but you do not have more than one.

To resolve this, you must either allocate space for an array of pointers to `char` and fill that array with such pointers (perhaps to those various `char` in `S`) or you must change `buscar_str` to accept a pointer to an array, such as `char (*S)[200]`, or, less likely, a pointer to an array of arrays, such as `char (*S)[1000][200])`. For the former, you would pass `S` to `buscar_str`. For the latter, you would pass `&S` to `buscar_str`.

We cannot tell you which of these options is suitable for your situation without further information.