# Why is `unsigned char buf[length]` not compatible to `unsigned char**`?

Tags: c++, arrays

C++ 12.2.0 throws the error

> error: cannot convert ‘unsigned char (*)[91]’ to ‘unsigned char**’

on the following c++11 code snippet:

```
unsigned char buffer[91];

// int i2d_PUBKEY(EVP_PKEY *a, unsigned char **pp);
ptrdiff_t length = i2d_PUBKEY(m_pkey, &buffer);
```

- Defining `unsigned char *buffer` fixes the error, but leaves the array length unspecified.
- I had assumed `unsigned char buffer[91]` decays into `unsigned char *buffer`.

Explicitely casting like `i2d_PUBKEY(m_pkey, (unsigned char **)&buffer)` makes the error go away, but the code segfaults then. I suppose there is something fundamental I don't understand with respect to C++ arrays.

Can someone tell me how to write the code above so it works as intended?

Comment: Related / possible duplicated: [Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4470950/11082165)

Comment: I removed the C99 variable length array tag since VLAs don't exist in standard C++ and there are no C/extension VLAs in this question.

Comment: @Brian61354270, thanks. My original code uses `buffer[length]`, but I omitted this from the question for brevity. Will remove my reference to VLA from the question as well.

Comment: What should `pp` argument point to? What does `i2d_PUBKEY` do? *If `pp` is not `NULL`, it writes the encoded data to the buffer at `*pp`, and **increments it to point after the data just written**.*

Comment: Think about the addresses and memory involved here. `unsigned char**` is a pointer to a pointer to an `unsigned char`. If you dereference such a pointer, you'd arrive at a location in memory that contains a pointer to a `unsigned char`. If you then dereference that pointer, you'd arrive at a location in memory that contains a `unsigned char`.

Comment: The dupe is irrelevant, there are no 2D arrays here.

Comment: Side note: `std::array` and `std::vector` are your friends. Forget that C-style arrays exist.

Comment: [Minimal fix](https://godbolt.org/z/68b3vrnbc).

Comment: @Evg, thank you, got it. Seems to work. If you provide it as answer, I'm to happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that neither of two pointers in the signature is `const`. This alone should warn you because the function could modify data at **two** different locations, but you're passing only one (unless you expect `buffer` itself to change, which I guess you don't). The documentation reads:

> If `pp` is not `NULL`, it writes the encoded data to the buffer at `*pp`, and increments it to point after the data just written.

Let's introduce the second variable to be modified:

```
unsigned char* ptr = &buffer[0];
```

Now we can pass this variable to `i2d_PUBKEY()`:

```
i2d_PUBKEY(/* ... */, &ptr);
```

This call will write data into `*ptr`, i.e. into `buffer`. `ptr` itself will be modified, and that's why `ptr` can't be passed by value and a second pointer is needed - or a reference to a pointer if `i2d_PUBKEY()` were a C++ function.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xcW5qr8Mn)